# magic chef gas stove no clicking, gfci is tripped, won't reset

Tags: gfci, gas, stove

just like usual, I cleaned the magic chef gas stove Under the top. the gfci in the next room went red, no clicking, no pilot, but it's clean. What's wrong?

Comment: If you reset the GFI, does it trip again?

Comment: it stays tripped. the stove is not plugged in the gfci that's tripped. it's in the next plug over and when I unplugged the stove, most lights in the apt went out.

Comment: Can you check the breaker panel. I would be concerned with lights going out when you unplugged the stove. if this is a newer place and it has arc fault breakers one of them could have tripped when you unplugged the stove I could understand that. if that is not the case something is seriously wrong and should be checked.

Answer (score 1):

There are five possibilities.  Note that there could be more than one of these underlying the problem.

1. You aren't resetting the GFI correctly.  Move the breaker handle all the way to off before turning it back on.
2. The GFI is broken.
3. The range is broken.
4. Something else on the same circuit is broken.
5. If the circuit has *never* worked correctly, the circuit wiring might have been done incorrectly, or it has changed.  A peek inside the circuit breaker panel for loose wires could identify the answer.

We need more information to determine which problem it is.

Answer (score 0):

Either the GFCI is malfunctioning and needs to be replaced, or thge stove's electronics are malfunctioning and need to be repaired. Without more information we can't tell you which.