# Gas stove is tripping circuit breaker

Tags: repair

Yesterday, we ran cleaner option on the gas oven and earlier today finish cleaning it with baking soda and vinegar.  Tonight we tried to turn on the oven and it keeps tripping the breaker

Comment: Brand and model number if the appliance

Comment: And what type of breaker? If you're not sure, take a picture. Because it is gas, it may be a small circuit (electric ovens have big 240V circuits) and because of that, it may have GFCI and/or AFCI which may be a factor in this.

Comment: Have you considered that liquid might have gotten into part of the oven it shouldn't during the cleaning process?

Comment: Does the breaker have a "test" button on it?

Comment: Yes, When I push it  the breaker comes back on.  but when I turn on the oven on i goes off again

Comment: I am not sure of he Breaker id do believe it might 120V the plug is behind the oven I am not pulling it out.        yes I have considered the liquid might have sorted the electrical.     the Gas Oven is Magic Chef  I don;t know the model #  we bought it about 20 Years ago

Comment: It's a stove top right? Let's pop the top and have a look.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [magic chef gas stove no clicking, gfci is tripped, won't reset](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/90087/magic-chef-gas-stove-no-clicking-gfci-is-tripped-wont-reset)